# Receiving the follow error [Invalid break (SyntaxError)] when opening helper_method file using require

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby.  I have created a helper method file for my watir scripts.  When I try to run the script it hits this line:

```
require "C:/Sites/common/helper_methods"
```

and throws this error message:

```
C:/Sites/common/helper_methods.rb: C:/Sites/common/helper_methods.rb:1387: Invalid break (SyntaxError)
```

so I am not sure what the error means.

I have searched for an answer but can not find one that helps me figure out the message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Joe

Hi Paul,

*Here is the method before 1387*

```
#Write Subject Lines to file
def add_subject_line_to_file(s)

 project_path = Dir.pwd

 fileNamePath = File.join(project_path,'data_files','multi_add_discussion_files','multi_add_discussion_headers.txt')

 #Writing to new file
 open(fileNamePath,'a+'){ |f|
   f << "#{s}\n"
 }
end
```

which might be the problem

*the method after 1387*

```
#The following method will validate text at on the page not in a specific location
def text_validation(rt)

  #Validate comment displays
  if @browser.text.include? rt

        #Response
        response = "PASS!!! The following user comment was found [ #{rt} ]."
        write_to_file(response)

  else

        #Response
        response = "FAIL!!! The following user comment was NOT found [ #{rt} ]."
        write_to_file(response)

  end #End of Validate comment displays

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
C:/Sites/common/helper_methods.rb: 
C:/Sites/common/helper_methods.rb:1387: 
Invalid break (SyntaxError)
```

means there's an error parsing (SyntaxError) on line 1387 of helper_methods.rb ( ...helper_methods.rb:1387).

It's possible that the error occurs much earlier but the interpreter is only able to notice it at line 1387. Posting the lines around line 1387 may help diagnose further.

1378 is a lot of lines to have in one file. You may want to think about breaking those methods up into related hunks and include only the portions you need. Doing this would also help find the error if you could require 5 or 6 you know the error is in the one file you can't require. You could also try commenting out methods in the helper_methods until you find the one that triggers the problem.